# How can I use variable as global?

Tags: c++, imagemagick

Can I use class member variable as global?

I'd like to use class member variable as global like following.

```
// mfc_test5Dlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "Testview.h"
#include "atltypes.h"

Image m_image;<------------------HERE!!!
Image m_blurgray;<------------------HERE!!!


// Cmfc_test5Dlg dialog
class Cmfc_test5Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
...
```

and

```
// Testview.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mfc_test5.h"
#include "mfc_test5Dlg.h"

extern  char * fileposition;
extern int slider_val;

// CTestview
CTestview *global_TestView; 

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CTestview, CScrollView)

    CTestview::CTestview()
{
    global_TestView = this;
}

CTestview::~CTestview()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestview, CScrollView)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestview drawing

void CTestview::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();

    CSize sizeTotal;
    // TODO: calculate the total size of this view
    sizeTotal.cx = sizeTotal.cy = 100;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, sizeTotal);


}

void CTestview::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
    // TODO: add draw code here

        CRect rcWin;
GetWindowRect( &rcWin );
int ff;
ff=rcWin.Width();
rcWin.Height();

m_image.read("file"); <------------------HERE!!!
    DoDisplayImage();
```

But I've got some error as following.

```
------ Build started: Project: mfc_test5, Configuration: Release Win32 ------

InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "Release\mfc_test5.unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  All outputs are up-to-date.
ResourceCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
mfc_test5Dlg.obj : error LNK2005: "class Magick::Image m_image" (?m_image@@3VImage@Magick@@A) already defined in mfc_test5.obj
mfc_test5Dlg.obj : error LNK2005: "class Magick::Image m_blurgray" (?m_blurgray@@3VImage@Magick@@A) already defined in mfc_test5.obj
Testview.obj : error LNK2005: "class Magick::Image m_image" (?m_image@@3VImage@Magick@@A) already defined in mfc_test5.obj
Testview.obj : error LNK2005: "class Magick::Image m_blurgray" (?m_blurgray@@3VImage@Magick@@A) already defined in mfc_test5.obj
C:\work\mfc_test5\mfc_test5\Release\mfc_test5.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.94
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

As you can see above code, I'd like to use m_image as global class member variable.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you call the variables class members, when they clearly are not members of your class?

Comment: Maybe you want static member variables instead of global?

Comment: @TommyA is there any problem?

Comment: the problem is that the title is confusing and does not match what your question is about. Your class does not have any member variables (at least I didnt find any)

Comment: @tobi303 then what are they called these variable                                              Image m_image;<------------------HERE!!!
Image m_blurgray;<------------------HERE!!!

Comment: @cabot because someone named them that way, even if they are not member variable of anything. putting an m_ in front of a variable does not make them part of a class

Comment: They are called global variables of class type (specifically of type `Image`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declare** your variables in header using `extern` keyword

```
extern Image m_image;
extern Image m_blurgray;
```

and **define** these variables in a .cpp (source) file.

```
Image m_image;
Image m_blurgray;
```

Comment: Got it, then can I use above variables in global? What If I want to use same variable in another cpp, Is this can be possible way?

Comment: @cabot Yes, because those variables will *be* global variables.